# Appending to existing sequence file is overwriting the content

Tags: java, hadoop, sequencefile

I am using below code snippet for sequence file writer but it works fine if sequence file doesn't exist but it does then it overwrites the content rather than appending to it.

```
SequenceFile.Writer writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(FileContext.getFileContext(conf), conf, sequenceFile, Text.class, Text.class, CompressionType.NONE, null, new Metadata(), EnumSet.of(CreateFlag.CREATE, CreateFlag.APPEND));
```

Please note: I am using hadoop 2.7.2.

Can anyone please help on how do I append to an existing sequence file?

Also I tried below option as well but no luck:

```
Writer writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(conf, SequenceFile.Writer.file(sequenceFile), SequenceFile.Writer.keyClass(Text.class), SequenceFile.Writer.valueClass(Text.class), SequenceFile.Writer.appendIfExists(true), metadataOption);
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Writer` in case of SequenceFile.Writer like this:

```
Writer writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(//required params);
```

And then use the its append method.

```
Writer.append(param1, param2);
```

I hope [this link](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-2.7.2/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/io/TestSequenceFileAppend.java#L63-L140) may help You.

Here is the link [Allow appending to existing SequenceFiles](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7139). The issue has been solved in 2.7.2

Comment: Yes I tried the option given in link as well but still having the same issue.

Comment: hey! i added a new link to my answer. Check it. @user3400887

Comment: I tried with appendIf Exists one as well but same overwrite issue. I have updated the question with the another option I tried.